# Determine the value of the magnitude flux density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

To reproduce a classic experiment for measuring the magnetic flux density $\vec{ B}$ (magnetic induction), the arrangement illustrated in the figure below was set up. A coil composed of $4$ turns is attached to the right side of the balance and has its lower part subjected to a magnetic field, whose magnetic flux density is perpendicular to the plane of the turns. Initially, a current of $200$ mA flows through the coil counterclockwise, and the scale is balanced by a mass placed on the right pan. Then, the direction of the current is reversed, and the balance of the scale is restored by a mass of $20$ grams, placed on the left pan. Determine the value of the magnitude of the magnetic flux density $\vec{B}$ , expressed in gauss.

$X$: represents the magnetic field flux line "entering" the paper plane

-bobina = coil

I thought of something about Electromechanical Energy Conversion... I don't have much idea where to start the problem. Can anyone give me any hints?

This question was part of my 2019 higher education physics exam.

I considered that the mass initially placed on the right plate to balance the force $F_v_1$ was removed after the inversion
of the current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought of something about Electromechanical Energy Conversion

No, you need to consider the Lorentz force.
Especially see [Lorentz force - Force on a current-carrying wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Force_on_a_current-carrying_wire).
The force acting on a piece of wire (length $\ell$, current $I$) is
$$\vec{F}=I\vec{\ell}\times\vec{B}$$

Consider the forces on the 3 parts of the wire  separately.
You will find the forces on the left and right vertical parts cancel each other.
So only the force on the lower horizontal part remains.

Since this is a homework-like question, I will leave the rest of the solution  to you.

Answer (score 2):

$$F=\frac{BI}L$$ where $L=4\times 10 \text{ cm}$ the magnitude of $F$ is the same the direction opposite if you change the direction of the current. can you now figure out $F$ ans than $B$?